# Android WebView app resetting on rotation

Tags: java, android, webview

I am having some issues with webview where on rotation the app resets to the default URL. I have hunted round for a solution and tried a number on here and run into different issues with each.

This is what is in my .java code

```
package uk.co.grcade.grcade;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class GRcade extends Activity {

    WebView web;
    String webURL = "http://grcade.co.uk";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grcade);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            web.loadUrl(webURL);
        }

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl(webURL);
        web.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        web.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState )
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        web.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        web.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_grcade, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView web, String url) {
            web.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int ketCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((ketCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I got the code from a post on here but can't comment to ask why the line:

```
web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
```

is showing an unable to resolve symbol error, I am new to this whole thing so would appreciate some help on how I can get that error to go away and allow me to have a webview app that can be rotated without resetting back to the default page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in OnCreate method.
Your code

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_grcade);

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            web.loadUrl(webURL);
        }
.........
.........
```

You check if your Bundle object is not null and you load the URL. Instead, you should be restoring the state when the bundle object is not null. Something like this

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
            } else {
                webView.loadUrl("http://grcade.co.uk");
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I still have the issue with the second line I mentioned which stops me launching it in the emulator and if I // out the line I can launch the emulator but the app just crashes.

Comment: What's the version of Android studio your using?

Comment: Syncing the project with gradle files should help